# Taskkill /PID not working in GitBash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm trying to kill a process on GitBash on Windows10 using the taskkill command. However, I get the following error:

```
$ taskkill /pid 13588
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'C:/Program Files/Git/pid'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.
```

it works fine on cmd. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 89):

You have to use double slashes in this case:

```
taskkill //PID 13588
```

This is documented here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion
Look at the examples on this page, especially the `//foobar` example.

Comment: taskkill -F //PID 1848    // To force termination

Comment: I have the same problem on one of my Windows 8.1 machines, but on the other one, the problem is the opposite; double slashes get me "Invalid argument/option", but single slashes work. Any ideas?

Comment: none of these approaches worked for me, I just wanted a `bg PID` and I get "no such a job" Error again

Comment: try this --> taskkill //PID 2651 -F

Comment: Also taskkill //PID 12560 //F worked for me (double slashes on every params)

Comment: Just use `-` instead `taskkill -pid`

Answer (score 18):

Use `TSKILL processid`

Example:

```
TSKILL 1234
```

Comment: make sure to use the WPID to identify the process to kill (not the PID)

Comment: @EnricoGiurin great point, you can `< /proc/1234/winpid xargs tskill`

Answer (score 6):

To fix this I need to kill another additional program:

```
taskkill //F //IM "git-bash.exe"
taskkill //F //IM "bash.exe"
```

Answer (score 4):

To delete the child processes as well, use the "/T" argument.

> taskkill //PID 13588 //T

use double slashes before argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is what actually worked for me:

```
taskkill /F /IM mintty.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Run Git Bash as administrator

`taskkill -f -fi "services eq msiserver"`